# New-AzureRmADGroup doesn't have a way to indicate if a group is security enabled?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I feel like I am missing something.  I am looking to use New-AzureRmADGroup to create new groups in bulk -- the issue is I cannot see how to enable or disable a group as security enabled.  Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the command you are using `New-AzureRmADGroup` will always create a **Security** group.
So if you check the created group's properties using PowerShell, you will always find `SecurityEnabled: True`

You can create another type of group, i.e. an "**Office 365**" group using Azure Portal or a completely different PowerShell command (also a different module) i.e. `New-UnifiedGroup` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/New-UnifiedGroup?view=exchange-ps))

Here's a quick link to Microsoft Documentation on creating Azure AD Groups and the two types. ([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-groups-create-azure-portal))

[image]

[image]

- Security groups are good to manage access to Azure resources as a group instead of individual users. More info here: [Manage access to resources with Azure Active Directory groups](http://Manage%20access%20to%20resources%20with%20Azure%20Active%20Directory%20groups.)
- If you're interested in Office 365 groups and related PowerShell Commands, more info here: [Office 365 Groups](http://Office%20365%20Groups) and [Manage Office 365 Groups with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/manage-office-365-groups-with-powershell#office-365-groups-cmdlets)

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot.  The other thing I found is that by setting the MailNickname to "NotSet" it would ignore that field

Comment: @Shawn you're welcome, I 'm glad it helped :) ..Interesting info on the MaliNickname, I didn't know that part.